# How do I make a checkbox smaller than the default size?

Tags: css

How can I achieve a smaller checkbox input, for use in densely populated lists etc. using standard HTML + CSS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Resizing the checkbox input isn't reliable cross-browser.  Check out this site for some investigation:

[Styled checkboxes](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/form_controls/checkboxes/)

Comment: this great link is so outdated!

Comment: @whyoz Well this question was answered 6 years ago. That's equivalent to dinosaurs roaming the earth, a big comet and human revolution in tech terms.

Comment: Isn't it more like a dinosaur that hid inside the earth for millions of years, and evolved into a reptilian race just waiting to unleash havok, cross browser?  It's here...a new CSS3/HTML5, Bootstrap, or some evolved creature to help interact with this ancient beast?

Answer (score 5):

```
<style type="text/css">
    input[type='checkbox'] {
        width:10px;
        height:10px;
    }
</style>
```